# keyless ciphers of ROT13/47 ilk

Tags: encryption, rot13

Do you know of any other ciphers that performs like the ROT47 family?
My major requirement is that it'd be keyless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you might be looking for some "classical cryptography" solutions.

SUBSTITUTION CIPHERS are encodings where one character is substituted with another.  E.g. A->Y, B->Q, C->P, and so on.  The "Caesar Cipher" is a special case where the order is preserved, and the "key" is the offset.  In the rot13/47 case, the "key" is 13 or 47, respectively, though it could be something like 3 (A->D, B->E, C->F, ...).

---

TRANSPOSITION CIPHERS are ones that don't substitute letters, but ones that rearrange letters in a pre-defined way.  For example:

```
CRYPTOGRAPHY
```

may be written as

```
C Y T G A H
 R P O R P Y
```

So the ciphered output is created by reading the two lines left to right

```
CYTGAHRPORPY
```

---

Another property of rot13/47 is that it's REVERSABLE:

```
encode(encode(plaintext)) == plaintext
```

If this is the property you want, you could simply XOR the message with a known (previously decided) XOR value.  Then, XOR-ing the ciphertext with the same value will return the original plaintext.  An example of this would be the [memfrob function](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/libc/Trivial-Encryption.html), which just XORs a buffer with the binary representation of the number 42.

---

You also might check out other forms of ENCODINGS, such as [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) if that's closer to what you're looking for.

---

!! Disclaimer - if you have data that you're actually trying to protect from anyone, don't use any of these methods.  While entertaining, all of these methods are trivial to break.